# Python Word Frequency

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I am messing around with Python trying to write a program that inputs a list of words from a text file and outputs the number of times each word appears. I am very close but for some reason cannot get this program to run. I am utilizing a counter and a dictionary to count the numbers of appearances for each word and storing them as the values and the keys

Can anyone spot where my program is getting held up? The program doesn't run it freezes and then after I click enter it says:

```
./wordFrequency.py: line 3: syntax error near unexpected token `('
./wordFrequency.py: line 3: `def main():'
```

I am very confused. Code below:

```python
import collections

def main():
    mylist = open("C:/path/files/csc223/assignment1/words.dat") as f:
        lines = f.read().splitlines()
    mycount = []
    for i in range(len(mylist)):
        mycount.append(myinp.count(mylist[i]))

    mydict = dict(zip(mylist, mycount))
    print (mydict)

main()
```

Comment: @lambo477 input is standard in python

Comment: Yes, but if you type `myinp = input().split()` into the console you get an error

Comment: @lambo477, do you? I don't.

Comment: Your program does not get held up, it's the function `input()` that is, well, waiting for the user's input before it proceeds (that's why when you press Enter, the program continues).

Answer (score 2):

Looks like you're calling bash interpreter for your script. Try using `python wordFrequency.py` instead of `./wordFrequency.py`.

Comment: what should i do about my input statement

Comment: `myinp = input().split()` command looks perfectly sane. However, when you get your script running, you might want to revise `mylist = open("/files/words.dat")` since `open` returns file object, not list.

Comment: If you would like to run the file as `./wordFrequency.py`, you can always add the proper shebang at the top of the file.  Usually `#!/usr/bin/env python` does the trick.  And then of course from the command line `chmod +x wordFrequency.py` if you haven't already but it seems like you have since the file at least tries to execute.

Comment: i revised to  mylist = open("C:/path/files/words.dat")      as f:
  lines = f.read().splitlines()     But this still gives me a syntax error

Comment: What error message do you see? If it contains `syntax error near unexpected token` then you're still trying to use `bash`. If it is `SyntaxError: invalid syntax` then you've managed to call Python interpreter and it's up to you now to give it a fight; if you fail here, just create another question on SO. (and there is no `a = open(...) as b:` construction, there is `with open(...) as b:`)